# Simplest way to get current user logged in Keycloak

Tags: javascript, java, keycloak, openid-connect

I have implemented a really simple keycloak integration on my maven java web app.
Assuming I am calling a url directly for the keycloak log in page .

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myclientid&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http//localhost:8080/mypage.html
```

After entering my username & password on success i am being redirected on mypage.html , the url is like this

```
http://localhost:8080/mypage.html?session_state=c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661&code=5d4aebda-54d8-41ad-8205-c4d7e021770f.c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661.d5c1b6ac-c427-46da-8509-f2689849103b
```

If I break this down its

```
http://localhost:8080/mypage.html?
session_state=c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661&
code=5d4aebda-54d8-41ad-8205-c4d7e021770f.c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661.d5c1b6ac-c427-46da-8509-f2689849103b
```

What would be the simplest - easiest way to get the user currently logged so i can display it's name ?

Comment: Is that user-data you want to display stored in your own database? Or is it already available via Keycloak? If yes, please refer to the Keycloak documentation also.

Comment: It's stored in the keycloak database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the requests you have made you have not completed the OIDC code flow.

I'm assuming that your java application is acting as the OIDC client, in which case it will need to exchange the authorization code for access, id and refresh tokens by calling the token endpoint of your realm.

e.g.

> POST /auth/realms/mmyrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.example.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
>
> grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
> &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb

[A description of the Token Request](https://rograce.github.io/openid-connect-documentation/explore_auth_code_flow#token-request)

The simplest way would be to use a Java OIDC Client or OAuth2 client to do the authorisation and cod exchange for you and provide OAuth2/OIDC token primitives for you to code against.

Have a look at:
[Scribe Java OAuth2 client](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava)
[Nimbus OIDC SDK](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk)

The details of the user will be in claims within the tokens returned by the token endpoint, if you are including the user claims in your tokens.

Edit:
The OIDC Authorization code flow is one of the OIDC authorisation flows. It provides the benefit of not exposing any of the actual tokens to the user agent - e.g. web browser - and allows the oidc client to authenticate with the token server before exchanging the code for the OIDC tokens

At a high level the following occurs:

1. OIDC Client makes an authentication request
2. Client authenticates - this could be an end user
3. Authorisation server returns an Authorisation code - on a redirect - to the client
4. OIDC Client retrieves Access, ID and Refresh Tokens from the authorisation server's token endpoint
5. If needed User info is retrieved from the UserInfo endpoint or thge access token is inspected using the introspect endpoint

Details of the actual user will be in claims with in the ID token, which is a plain JWT.
Keycloak allows you to embed the claims in the Access token too.

After authentication with Keycloak you will be redirected back to your web applications redirect URI.

As *per* your breakdown

```
http://localhost:8080/mypage.html?
session_state=c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661&
code=5d4aebda-54d8-41ad-8205-c4d7e021770f.c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661.d5c1b6ac-c427-46da-8509-f2689849103b
```

Your requst handler will need to extract the code from that request and then make another call to keycloak to exchange the authorisation code for Access, ID and refresh tokens

e.g.

```
POST /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8180
ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: <whatever method your oidc client is usingL
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=5d4aebda-54d8-41ad-8205-c4d7e021770f.c9482da3-50ff-4176-bf3c-54227271c661.d5c1b6ac-c427-46da-8509-f2689849103b&
client_id=myclientid&
redirect_uri=....
```

Ideally you have a route handler for accepting the tokens - maybe a tokens enpoint that also accepts query parameters that indicate the original uri requested so that you can redirect back to that if this is a user facing web application.
If it is completely programatic then you can achive all of it using the nimbus sdk.

The has a good summary of the various parts of Authorization Code flow
https://rograce.github.io/openid-connect-documentation/explore_auth_code_flow

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick reply . Are you describing two different ways there, one that is sending a post request using the code and another way by using a client adapter?

If yes i do not want to use a client adapter because it changes the structure of your project (protected pages) from what i saw and the only thing i need is to display the name.

I am goiing to check the link you sent me "A description of the Token Request" . Hopefully i can figure this out (considering i have no idea how to send a POST request right now).

Comment: Also if yes if you know and it's not too much trouble can you explain the flow on the POST request, i understand that with the auth code i have on the generated url i can get some information back using a POST request.

So i send the code to the token endpoint ? and that brings back a token that then i can call other methods and get the username i need? like token.getUserInfo(); or something ? 

Thank you again.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're referring to by client adaptor. Are you referring to the Keycloak client adaptor? Which would imply that you are running in an application server.

Comment: Hello thanks for the quick reply once again, if you mean https://www.keycloak.org/downloads -> Client adapters no im not running one . Only thing i do is what i mention on the thread here. It works fine so far , logging in other clients under the same realm works as well so i have SSO . Were you describing two different methods above (one being POST request, other being the client adapter ) or ? Sorry im really new and still getting confused easily.

Comment: No, you need to make serveral requests to the authorisation server - in this case Keycloak. I've added a high level summary of OIDC code flow to the answer

Comment: Ok i hear you and thank you.
So i have step 1,2,3 and now i need to give the code (that i will somehow fetch from the url)
  grant_type=authorization_code&code=give_code_here
on a post method along with other info  . Then i will get something in return that i can use that something doing more requests to the authorization server to get any info i need.

That's my understanding . Maybe i will start reading more about servlets and if i stuck i will make a new thread . If you have any resource that can help me out like POST , fetching the url etc i would appreciate it 

Thank you again.

Comment: If you're using Servlets, then maybe have a look at Pac4j. Its a security library that does OIDC as well as a bunch of other protocols.

Under the JEE support is has servlet filters
http://www.pac4j.org/

Comment: For a more in depth understanding have a read of the OAuth2 RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749, Bearer token usage RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750 and the OIDC specification https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html (which may be a little confronting)